# Preparing Hardcopy and Online Page

Tags: formatting, third-party-applications, latex

I am writing a book and I want to post it online (into various web pages) and also want to have a hardcopy. The book has a lot of figures and math equations. How can I prepare the posts to minimize formatting?

Currently, I am writing using LaTeX, but I understand it is not efficient at all, because copy and paste from a text file and then formatting for a web page take a lot of time.

Is there any better way?

Comment: but are you using wordpress or not? if you do not know here is for question about wordpress

Comment: Obviously yes. I use Wordpress. The question is how to prepare a Wordpress post that is useful for hardcopy as well or how to prepare a hardcopy (using Word, LaTeX, Lyx, or something else) that can be posted with minimal formatting.

Comment: I would use something like Codepen, then embed the "pens" into WP Posts. Wordpress is made for blogging, not for storing code. You are propably running into may issues, because code fragments will get stripped / broken a lot.